# Passing Different Classes to Same Method

Tags: c#, class, parameter-passing

I'm setting up a little "shop" system for a small self-teaching project. I can get it to work if I define each class argument accepted by the form, but what if I want to pass different classes with different properties?

Here is my item class, each with different properties.

```
public class Items
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public int GoldValue { get; set; }
}

public class Weapons : Items
{
    public int MinDamage { get; set; }
    public int MaxDamage { get; set; }

    public Weapons(int id, string itemName, int itemType, int goldValue, int minDamage, int maxDamage)
    {
        ID = id;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemType = itemType;
        GoldValue = goldValue;
        MinDamage = minDamage;
        MaxDamage = maxDamage;
    }
}

public class Armors : Items
{
    public int Defense { get; set; }

    public Armors(int id, string itemName, int itemType, int goldValue, int defense)
    {
        ID = id;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemType = itemType;
        GoldValue = goldValue;
        Defense = defense;
    }
}

public class Shields : Items
{
    public int Defense { get; set; }

    public Shields(int id, string itemName, int itemType, int goldValue, int defense)
    {
        ID = id;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemType = itemType;
        GoldValue = goldValue;
        Defense = defense;
    }
}

public class Potions : Items
{
    public int HPHeal { get; set; }
    public int MPHeal { get; set; }
    public int SPHeal { get; set; }

    public Potions(int id, string itemName, int itemType, int goldValue, int hpHeal, int mpHeal, int spHeal)
    {
        ID = id;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemType = itemType;
        GoldValue = goldValue;
        HPHeal = hpHeal;
        MPHeal = mpHeal;
        SPHeal = spHeal;
    }
}
```

Here is my Shop form.

```
public partial class Shop : Form
{
    Weapons item1;
    Armors item2;
    Shields item3;
    int Gold;

    public Shop(int gold, Weapons weapon1, Armors armor1, Shields shield1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        item1 = weapon1;
        item2 = armor1;
        Gold = gold;
        item1Lbl.Text = item1.ItemName + "   " + item1.MinDamage + " - " + item1.MaxDamage + " Damage -- " + item1.GoldValue + " Gold";
        item2Lbl.Text = item2.ItemName + "   " + item2.Defense + " Defense -- " + item2.GoldValue + " Gold";
        item3Lbl.Text = item3.ItemName + "   " + item3.Defense + " Defense -- " + item3.GoldValue + " Gold";
    }

    public Shop(int gold, Potions potion1, Potions potion2, Potions potion3)
    {

    }

    private void Shop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buy1Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Gold >= item1.GoldValue)
        {
            Equipment.ChangeWeapon(item1.ID, item1.ItemName, item1.MinDamage, item1.MaxDamage);
            Equipment.Gold -= item1.GoldValue;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need " + (item1.GoldValue - Gold) + " additional gold.");
        }
    }

    private void buy2Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Gold >= item2.GoldValue)
        {
            Equipment.ChangeArmor(item2.ID, item2.ItemName, item2.Defense);
            Equipment.Gold -= item2.GoldValue;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need " + (item2.GoldValue - Gold) + " additional gold.");
        }
    }

    private void buy3Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Gold >= item3.GoldValue)
        {
            Equipment.ChangeShield(item3.ID, item3.ItemName, item3.Defense);
            Equipment.Gold -= item3.GoldValue;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need " + (item3.GoldValue - Gold) + " additional gold.");
        }
    }
}
```

What would be an efficient way to set it up so that I can pass any item type (Weapons, Armors, Potions, etc) to the same form without having to write code explicitly for each possibility?

Comment: I usually put controls into arrays to make code simple.  Like :             List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };  This is still code but easy to setup.